# How can I display Schema data depending on entry point (e.g button used)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I would be grateful for help with the below:

I would like to know how I can display schema data depending on the 'point of entry'. for example, say I have 6 buttons labelled1 1-6, each button will display all entries of a schema when clicked on, however, say I wanted to only display entries with a title of "Section 1" when using the button labelled 1 and all entries with the title of "Section 2" when using the button labelled 2 etc.. - So, in short, each button displays the same schema, but each button displays data depending on the title. (I hope that this makes sense)

Comment: If I rephrase it correctly - Do you mean to say you've a collection with documents with similar data having different data in title attribute ? So if you click on a button then all you need is data related to it's title ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Can you please give us what have you tried, Or if you completely need  help from scratch then look into these : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose && https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find , Also just to give basic idea - Once you create a respective schema + model for a collection then you can pass a dynamic variable to model.find({title : 'Section 1'}) or .find({title : 'Section 2'}) should get you results needed, You can send respective value from client on respective button click, please ignore this if I misunderstand you ask !

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Thank you, that is very helpful. Would I need to use a click event for this?

Comment: I've not worked on client side much, but with bare minimum knowledge I can say yes you've to !! From the first link you can start from section 'Mongoose primer', try it out & update this question if you're having any issues..